# How to construct noun forms of verbs?

Tags: verbes, noms, suffixes, substantivation

In English a noun form of the doer of a verb is usually formed by '-er' sound, e.g. *run - runner*, *teach - teacher*, *sell - seller*. Then the noun form of the action of the verb is usually the '-ing' form, e.g. *teach - teaching*, *run - running*, *sell - selling*.
Is there a comparative way to construct noun from of French verbs?

P.S. I'm not a native speaker of English or French.

Answer (score 8):

The usual doer suffixes are *-eur/-euse*, *-(a)teur/-(a)trice* and *-ant/ante*. There is more variation with the associated action nouns suffixes, including *-ement*, *-ation*, *-age* and the lack of suffix.

- Chanter -> Chanteur -> Chant
- Courir -> Coureur -> Course
- Dessiner -> Dessinateur -> Dessin
- Enseigner -> Enseignant -> Enseignement
- Former -> Formateur -> Formation
- Imprimer -> Imprimeur -> Impression
- Raffiner -> Raffineur -> Raffinage
- Vendre -> Vendeur -> Vente

Comment: Why (a)reuse? The usual pair seems to be (at)eur/(at)rice. As for actions, -age are quite common : brosser->brossage.

Comment: @GAMPUB I didn't wrote (a)reuse but (a)teuse. The latter is indeed almost nonexistent, I only found the rare "mateuse". I agree -age is common, answer updated to list it .

Comment: '@jlliagre sorry about the (a)teuse typo. My actual point was that I could see any example. Your mateuse is an-eur/-euse instance just like chanteur/chanteuse.